# Error when creating a new section

Tags: sectioning, errors, memory

I wanted to split a section of my document into to two sections, so I went write \section{title} as usual in the place where I wanted the new section to start. I get this huge error message (the names related to me and my document have been edited):

```
! \OML/cmm/m/it/12 p[]\U/msb/m/n/12 Z[] \OT1/cmr/m/n/12 : \OML/cmm/m/it/12 f[][]\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 (\OML/cmm/m/it/12 f\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 )
\OMS/cmsy/m/n/12 [][41]Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 1575--1576[][42] ("(...).bbl")
[43]Package atveryend Info: Empty hook 'BeforeClearDocument' on input line 1585.Package atveryend Info: Empty hook 'AfterLastShipout'
on input line 1585.("(...).aux")Package atveryend Info: Executing hook 'AtVeryEndDocument' on input line 1585.Package
atveryend Info: Executing hook 'AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 1585.Package rerunfilecheck Info: File '"(...)".out'
has not changed.(rerunfilecheck) Checksum: D75D04EAB87035039D02780E45EA715F;2097.LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.Package
atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryVeryEnd' on input line 1585.)Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:21000 strings out of 493323395671
string characters out of 3139054484122 words of memory out of 300000023933 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+20000019068 words of
font info for 76 fonts, out of 3000000 for 90001141 hyphenation exceptions out of 819169i,14n,92p,1257b,968s stack positions out of
5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s<(...)\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\pk\ljfour\public\bbm\dpi600\bbm8.pk>
<(...)\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\pk\ljfour\public\bbm\dpi600\bbm12.pk><(...)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/
type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb><(...)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/
fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmex10.pfb><(...)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb><(...)/
MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi12.pfb><(...)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi6.pfb>
<(...)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi8.pfb><(...)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
<(...)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb><(...)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr17.pfb>
<(...)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr6.pfb><(...)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr8.pfb>
<(...)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb><(...)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy6.pfb>
<(...)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy8.pfb><(...)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti10.pfb>
<(...)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti12.pfb><(...)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti8.pfb>
<(...)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/symbols/msbm10.pfb>Output written on "(...)" (43 pages,
505706 bytes).PDF statistics:752 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)227 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)237 words of extra
memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Strangely, this does not happen if: I do this in another place of the document (I am currently doing it right before the last subsection), I begin a \section*, or I begin a \subsection. I have tried cheating and starting the subsection in another place, then copying the body of the text, but I got the same error afterwards. I see memory being mentioned in the error message so I should point out that the document should be very light: no images or diagrams...

**Edit** I compiled separately parts of the document, and here is the code that seems to be causing problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabto}
\TabPositions{2 cm, 4 cm, 6 cm, 8 cm}

\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength\cftbeforetoctitleskip{5cm}
\setlength\cftaftertoctitleskip{2cm}

\usepackage{appendix}

\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem*{definition*}{Definition}

\newtheorem*{lemma*}{Lemma}
\newtheorem*{proposition*}{Proposition}
\newtheorem*{theorem*}{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{corollary*}{Corollary}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{notation}{Notation}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{comment}[theorem]{Comment}
\newtheorem{question}[theorem]{Question}

\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{im}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Ab}{Ab}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Tor}{Tor}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\subsection{Subsection 1}

\begin{definition}
For $k \geq 0$, define $C^n_b(G, \mathbb{Z}_p)_k := \{ f : G^{n+1} \to p^{-k} \mathbb{Z}_p : f \text{ is continuous and } \im ( \delta f) \subset \mathbb{Z}_p \}.$
Define $C^n_b(G, \mathbb{Z}_p)_\infty := \{ f : G^{n+1} \to \mathbb{Q}_p : f \text{ is continuous and bounded and } \im (\delta f) \subset \mathbb{Z}_p \},$ which is the directed union of the $C^n_b(G, \mathbb{Z}_p)_k$.
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Now I get the same error message if I compile this, and it does not go away if I replace section by section* or subsection. However, it does go away if I take away small things from the definition, like, the first `C^n_b(G, \mathbb{Z}_p)_k` or the first `\im`, or the first `\delta`... For some reason it seems that it is only with everything together that I get the error, so I cannot single out one thing that may be causing problems...

Comment: Unfortunately, the log has been reformatted into unintelligibility.  The memory reporting, as best I can tell, is simply the normal report at the end of any job.  But what we really need is an actual compilable example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` that demonstrates the problem, that potential helpers can copy and paste to experiment with.

Comment: Please provide an MWE (code from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows the error you are getting. As it is we have no idea what you might, or might not, have done.

Comment: I just added a full code (sorry, I'm new!)

Comment: I get no error from your sample code.

Comment: @egreg could there be a problem with my version of mixtex or even my computer then? Does this kind of things happen?